# Node js - How to pause execution of subsequent lines of code while waiting for user input in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, user-input, readline

I'm new to node.js and learning it on the fly. I have written a code to prompt for userinput from CLI with timeout. The problem is, the subsequent lines of code are executed and not paused while waiting for user input. how do i achieve this in node. Below is my code

```
var readline = require('readline');

var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

waitForUserInput = function (timeout) {
var timer = setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("Process Resumed..");
    rl.close();
}, timeout);

rl.question("Press Enter to Continue..!!", function () {
    console.log("Process Resumed..");
    clearTimeout(timer);
    rl.close();
});}
```

Method Invocation is

```
waitForUserInput(5000);
```

As of now if i do a console.log("Hello"); the output is

> Process Paused. Press Enter to Continue..!!
>   Hello

I want the console.log message only after user input or timeout.

Comment: You can't do that.  Instead, use promises.

Comment: Can you give an example.

Answer (score 0):

You should never stop execution of a Node.js process. Node.js is build on top of an `EventLoop`. In Node.js your code should work in asynchronously - you ask the user for keyboard input and register a piece of code that will be triggered once the the user finished the input.

For any kind of command line input I recommend using the [Inquirer.js package](https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js). You should create a `prompt` and handle the user input in the `then` block (`then` is called when a promise fulfilled without errors)